# Linux Firefox Permission Denied (Selenium, Python, Firefox)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, selenium, firefox

When trying to run a python script that uses Python, Selenium, Firefox (geckodriver) I get permission denied on Linux. Firefox is an older version (66.0.5) due to this being one of the few versions that supports proxy auth with username and password from inside the code when being prompted to an alert.

I am running this via ssh on a server. Firefox and geckodriver both have exec permission. I have access to root. Both Firefox and Geckodriver are the appropriate installations (x64, Linux). This setup works perfectly on my machine (Windows -- albeit both firefox and gecko are technically different due to them being the Windows versions).

When running the script I am getting "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 255". Upon opening geckodriver.log or trying to run ./firefox I get the access denied.